# Enable "Use network-provided values" programatically in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to be able to check this option programatically in on create...after prompting user ofchurs

[image]

Something like

```
if (android.systemtime==false)
 {
  systemtime=true;
  }
```

is this possible? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`Settings.System.AUTO_TIME`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AUTO_TIME) settings (which was moved to `Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME` in API level 17). Before API level 17 was introduced you could both read and change that value, but now this value is read-only for non-system apps.

```
private boolean isAutoTimeEnabled() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        // For JB+
        return Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) > 0;
    }
    // For older Android versions
    return Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0) > 0;
}
```

Comment: so are you saying its impossible to set in new android versions?

Comment: Right, not possible to change that value in Android 4.2.x and above.

Comment: On older Android versions you'd set that value to true with `Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 1);`. And of course, would need `"android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"`

Comment: it is possible to check use network provided values chekbox pro-grammatically?I want to check that checkbox using code.How can I do it?